# How do I manually iterate x and y values of a plot and apply the x,y indices to a heatmap function?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a very large data file that includes many snapshots
of the same Nodes in a computing cluster. 
I am measuring datarate between each connected endpoint and want to display the result in a heatmap.

However because there are so many snapshots of the same connection in the data file a normal plot will result in thousands of datapoints stacked on top of each other which will just produce an unreadable image - so i plan on using STATS to reduce the information per connection to 3 images with the information min, max, mean.

I do not know how to properly use the plot function to achieve this and the documentation for gnuplot only assumes preprocessed clean(non redundant matrix) data files which is not an option for me.

I have already managed to produce an array of the average datarate for each connected pair(i,j) and store the data in avg[1+i+j*max] and it appears to do what I intend it to do.

now what would be left to do is something that resembles

```
plot i:j:avg[1+i+j*max] with image
```

My current code(as seen below) uses the data file to solect the x,y values and then applies avg[...] in regards to x,y as the z value. This results in many many stacked drawings of the same value which can be identified by some of the data being more fat than others and is probably the root cause of why my images won't come out pretty. Therefore I'm trying to just iterate once over (x,y) from 0 to n each and draw the z-value once per (x,y)-pair.

I am not sure how to manually tell the plot command that it should iterate x and y each from 0 to n and then use the avg[...] as z value to draw the image

the current gnuplot snipped

```
# Color runs from white to green
set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
set cblabel "Score"
unset cbtics
stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using (column(10)) nooutput
set cbrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]

set output 'heatmap.png'
set title 'heatmap'
set xlabel 'en_id'
set ylabel 'pn_id'
set xrange [-1:10]
set yrange [-1:10]
set xtics 1
set ytics 1

stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using (column(1)) nooutput
max_en = STATS_max
num_en = max_en + 1
stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using (column(2)) nooutput
max_pn = STATS_max
num_pn = max_pn + 1
print sprintf("num_en = %d", num_en)
print sprintf("num_pn = %d", num_pn)


array Avg[num_en * num_pn]
ind(a,b) = 1+a+b*num_pn
getavg(a,b) = Avg[ind(a,b)]
do for [i=0:max_en] {
    do for [j=0:max_pn] {
    index = ind(i,j)
    stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using ($1 == i && $2 == j && $3 == 10 ? column(10) : 1/0) nooutput
    print sprintf("index = %d",index)
    Avg[index] = STATS_mean
    print sprintf("Avg[%2d,%2d] = %f",i,j,Avg[index])
    }
}

plot 'NxN_10GB.dat' using 1:2:(Avg[1+$1+$2*num_pn]) with image , \
     'NxN_10GB.dat' using 1:2:(sprintf("%g",Avg[1+$1+$2*num_pn])) with labels
```

this is a data snipped there are roughly 360 snapshots/connectionpair($1,$2). I am only interested in column 1,2 and 10 for now

```
en_id pn_id #en #pn time(sec) completions msg_size byte total_data(Gb) datarate(Gb/s)
0 0 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 1 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 2 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 3 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 4 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 5 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 6 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 7 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 8 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
0 9 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 0 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 1 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 2 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 3 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 4 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 5 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 6 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 7 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 8 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
1 9 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
2 0 10 10 10.0002 531 5048576 2680793856 21.4464 2.14459
2 1 10 10 10.0002 531 5048576 2680793856 21.4464 2.14459
2 2 10 10 10.0002 531 5048576 2680793856 21.4464 2.14459
3 3 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
3 4 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
3 5 10 10 10.0002 532 5048576 2685842432 21.4867 2.14863
```

So a standart heatmap should color the square at index i,j with color_code(value(i,j)).

All of the measured datarate is very very close together (which is actually a good thing) so no suprise we see a rather boring uniform image:

[image: set cbrange [0:STATS_max]]

However if i manipulate the color range to be very close to the average results to get more contrast I am startig to to see dire effects:
[image: set cbrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]]

I have 3 theories for what could cause this:

1. currently we draw every single connection entry(however with the same value). So stacking so many points may result in weird behaviour(we can see this with the more fat values which had more data points)
2. the squares for some reason overlap
3. the cbrange is just too small to properly compute the right color(but I doubt that)

Regarding 1. this is what I would like to confirm with this question.

edit:

on a hunch i produced some fake data to reduce the avg datarate on one of the nodes. 
but the result as far from expected. I am absolutely confused now :( 
[image]

as we can see (1,1) avg dropped to ~0.5 and should simply appear in a more light green - but what is this?!

edit2:

I produced some sample data to see whether I am still sane.
1 data point for each (x,y)-pair produces exactly the result I am looking for:
[image]

so solving my problem definitely comes back to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `++` special filename to create a list of (x,y) points, which you can then use to index your array. See `help ++` to see how to set the spacing of those points using `set urange`, `set samples`, and so forth. Keep in mind that those coordinates are floating points, so you have to round them to the nearest integer if you want to use them as array indices.

Something like this might work for you:

```
reset

set palette rgbformula -7,2,-7
1set cblabel "Score"
unset cbtics
stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using (column(10)) nooutput
set cbrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]

#set output 'heatmap.png'
set title 'heatmap'
set xlabel 'en_id'
set ylabel 'pn_id'
set xtics 1
set ytics 1

stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using (column(1)) nooutput
max_en = STATS_max
num_en = max_en + 1
stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using (column(2)) nooutput
max_pn = STATS_max
num_pn = max_pn + 1
print sprintf("num_en = %d", num_en)
print sprintf("num_pn = %d", num_pn)

array Avg[num_en * num_pn]
ind(a,b) = 1+a+b*num_pn
getavg(a,b) = Avg[ind(a,b)]
do for [i=0:max_en] {
    do for [j=0:max_pn] {
    index = ind(i,j)
    stats 'NxN_10GB.dat' using ($1 == i && $2 == j && $3 == 10 ? column(10) : 1/0) nooutput
    print sprintf("index = %d",index)
    Avg[index] = STATS_mean
    print sprintf("Avg[%2d,%2d] = %f",i,j,Avg[index])
    }
}

set urange [0:num_en-1]
set vrange[0:num_pn-1]
set samples num_en
set isosamples num_pn
plot "++" using 1:2:(Avg[1+int($1+0.5)+int($2+0.5)*num_pn]) w image, \
     "++" using 1:2:(sprintf("%g",Avg[1+int($1+0.5)+int($2+0.5)*num_pn])) with labels
```

Answer (score 0):

My way to realize (what I guess) what you want would be the following:

Instead of carrying out `stats` `NxN` times with filtered data, pass your data only once and do you statistics yourself by extracting values for minimum, maximum, sum and count and put them into arrays. This approach would also tolerate if there is no data for one of your connections (see white square in graph below).

Plotting as a heatmap is one way.
You can also create a "heatmap-looking" plot by using `with boxxyerror`.
Another suggestion to plot your data is to plot it `with yerrorbars` and show the deviation from the average. With this it is maybe also easier to visualize the minimum and maximum values in the same plot.

The code:

```
### statistics: minimum, maximum, average
reset session
set size square
set key left

FILE = "NxN_10GB.dat"  # skip random generation section and replace $Data with FILE

# generate some random data
M = 10
N = 10
set print $Data
do for [i=1:500] {
    print sprintf("%d %d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 %g",int(rand(0)*N),int(rand(0)*M),rand(0)/100.+2.14)
}
set print

# get the size of the array
stats $Data u 1:2 nooutput
M = int(STATS_max_y+1)
N = int(STATS_max_x+1)
ConnectionsCount = M*N

# initialize arrays
array Min[ConnectionsCount]   
array Max[ConnectionsCount]   
array Sum[ConnectionsCount]
array Count[ConnectionsCount]
do for [i=1:ConnectionsCount] {
    Min[i] = NaN; Max[i] = NaN; Sum[i] = 0; Count[i] = 0
}

IndexNo(m,n) = m*N + n +1
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u \
        (a=Min[IndexNo($1,$2)], Min[IndexNo($1,$2)] = ($10>=a && (a==a)) ? a : $10, \
         b=Max[IndexNo($1,$2)], Max[IndexNo($1,$2)] = ($10<=b && (b==b)) ? b : $10, \
         Sum[IndexNo($1,$2)] = Sum[IndexNo($1,$2)] + $10, \
         Count[IndexNo($1,$2)] = Count[IndexNo($1,$2)]+1 ) with table
unset table

set xrange[-0.5:N-0.5]
set xtics out
set yrange[-0.5:M-0.5]
set ytics out

SumTotal = sum[i=1:ConnectionsCount] (Sum[i])
CountTotal = sum[i=1:ConnectionsCount] (Count[i])
AverageTotal = SumTotal/CountTotal
print AverageTotal

set samples ConnectionsCount  # number of samples for '+'
set multiplot layout 2,1
    plot '+' u (int($0)%N):(int($0/N)):(0.5):(0.5):(Sum[$0+1]/Count[$0+1]) w boxxyerror lc palette fs solid 1.0 not

    set title sprintf("Deviation of average from total average %g",AverageTotal)    
    set size nosquare
    set xlabel "Number of connection"
    set xrange[0:ConnectionsCount+1]
    set yrange[*:*]
    plot '+' u ($0+1):(Sum[$0+1]/Count[$0+1]-AverageTotal):(Min[$0+1]-AverageTotal):(Max[$0+1]-AverageTotal) \
        with yerr pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

The result:

[image]